# ¿Cómo distiguir entre archivos y directorios? (librerias estandar de C o C++)

Tags: c, c++11

Estoy haciedo esta función para ver el contenido de un directorio, y me gustaría que no me mostrase las carpetas (solo archivos).

```
void  GetPaths(const char* PathDir, bool recursive, bool files_only)
{
    struct dirent *ent;
    DIR *dir = opendir(PathDir);
    int x=0;  


    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {    
        if( string(ent->d_name)!="." && string(ent->d_name)!="..")
        {
            if(files_only && !S_ISDIR(ent->d_type))
            cout<<PathDir + string("\\") + string(ent->d_name) <<endl;


            if(recursive)
            {
                string new_pth = PathDir + string("\\") + string(ent->d_name);
                GetPaths(new_pth.c_str(), recursive, files_only);
            }
        }
        x++;
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

Para hacerlo iba a usar esto `if(files_only && !S_ISDIR(ent->d_type))`pero al compilar me está dando un error que dice que `S_ISDIR` no esxite, y que `struct dirent` no tiene un miembro llamado `d_type`.

He estado mirando el man y si lo tiene... por lo visto lo han eliminado en windows, posiblemente en linux si está...

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html

```
   struct dirent {
       ino_t          d_ino;       /* Inode number */
       off_t          d_off;       /* Not an offset; see below */
       unsigned short d_reclen;    /* Length of this record */
       unsigned char  d_type;      /* Type of file; not supported
                                      by all filesystem types */
       char           d_name[256]; /* Null-terminated filename */
   };
```

He probado a usar la libreria `#include <filesystem>` pero es de C++17... es demasiado nueva para mi compilador que solo soporta hasta C++11. Y por el momento no puedo actualizarlo hasta que ellos saquen una actualización.
http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/

En, fin... La Pregunta es: ¿Alguna otra forma estandar de distinguir entre archivos y carpetas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado!! :-)
La solución fue usar la libreria `stat.h`...

FUENTES:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html

La cosa queda algo tal que así:

```
#include<dirent.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void  GetPaths(const char* PathDir, bool recursive, bool files_only)
{
    struct dirent *ent;
    DIR *dir = opendir(PathDir);

    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if( string(ent->d_name)!="." && string(ent->d_name)!="..")
        {
            string new_pth = PathDir + string("\\") + string(ent->d_name);
            struct stat statbuf;
            stat(new_pth.c_str(), &statbuf);

            if(files_only && !S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
            cout<<PathDir + string("\\") + string(ent->d_name) <<endl;

            if(recursive)
            GetPaths(new_pth.c_str(), recursive, files_only);
        }

    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```